# Sketchy look of geometry

Tags: edges

How do I remove that small line extensions in EDIT mode that pop up from vertices and create that sketchy appearance in 2.8? I searched everywhere and cannot find option to turn that off. I like my geometry clean without those extra lines.

Thank You!

[image]